# Stockfish 15 is stronger than Stockfish 16?

Tags: stockfish

According to https://www.chess.com/news/view/stockfish-16-on-chesscom :

***Stockfish 16 is currently the most powerful chess engine in the world**. The engine's latest version is significantly stronger, winning 12 more game pairs (where each engine plays both sides of the same opening position) **as it loses against Stockfish 15**.*

Emphasis is mine, as those statements sound mutually exclusive to me i.e. it can't be the world strongest if it loses to its predecessor.

And even then I would have thought it's just a typo or something as it doesn't make too much sense, but then some personal experimentation revealed something peculiar:
I have installed both Chess.com, Chessis, and Stockfish 15 engine apps on my Android device. Chess.com is using Stockfish 16 (as per aforementioned article); Chessis was initially defaulted to use Stockfish 14, but I explicitly pointed to use Stockfish 15. What I've noticed over time is that Chessis (Stockfish 15) is in fact stronger than Chess.com (Stockfish 16).

So I am totally confused here: if this is true that the older version is stronger than newer, what's a point of releasing the new version?

Comment: The grammar isn't great here. They mean Sf16 wins 12 more game pairs *than* it loses to sf15.

Comment: Maybe the default resources that chess.com allocates (CPU, memory) are less than chessis?

Answer (score 2):

As qwr wrote in a comment, Stockfish 16 wins 12 more game pairs than it loses to Stockfish 15. "Game pairs" is used here because in engine chess it's standard to play two games at once, with the opening fixed, and both engines take turns to play White.

In other words, if you get the two engines to play a 1000-match series, you might see something like Stockfish 15 winning 10 games, Stockfish 16 winning 120 games, and the remaining games are drawn.

So no, Stockfish 15 is not stronger than Stockfish 16; it is weaker by a substantial margin.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

In the light of this, I guess the article refers to only the web version of Chess.com having been upgraded and not the mobile version. In fact, the mobile version IS probably lower than SF 15 since Chessis's with SF 15 beats it. 

I think it would be very helpful if the mobile version of chess.com allowed switching between available SF engines just like Chessis does.
Or at very least, to be able to see somewhere on the app, which SF version is being used there.

Comment: Why 10 -> 120? Is that multiplying by 12?

Comment: @qwr yes? I don't understand your question.

Comment: it says 12 more game pairs, not 12x?